# Save Third party Library Custom Object to NSUSerDefault

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

So,I am using the AFPhotoEditorController and there is property of it named as AFPhotoeditorSession that stores and tracks all user action.THis session class is custom object that inherits from NSObject,I have googled about how to save custom objects in NSUser Defaults  and came to know that We can save that class if that class conforms to protocol NSCoding ,I don't know that whether I can change this class,Because it is only.h file that I have in my custom framework of AviarySDk.

```
    NSData *myEncodedObject = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:
   [self.sessions objectAtIndex:0]]; // self.session an array of one object of AFPhotoeditorSession
        NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [defaults setObject:myEncodedObject forKey:@"myEncodedObjectKey"];
        [defaults synchronize];
        NSData *data1 = [defaults objectForKey:@"myEncodedObjectKey"];
        AFPhotoEditorSession *obj = (AFPhotoEditorSession *)[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData: data1];
        NSLog(@"%@",obj);
```

I am getting error like :

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<AFPhotoEditorSession 0x1c5fa0f0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key modified.'
```

And you can check the AFPhotoEditor Session class at [PhotoEditorSession](http://www.aviary.com/content/staticdocs/ios/Classes/AFPhotoEditorSession.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can make the class conform to `NSCoding` by declaring and defining a category which conforms to that protocol and implements the necessary methods.

Comment: Where I can implement the **initwithencoder** or other method that are necceassary for NSCoding becuase I don't have .m file for this AFPhotoEditorSession,thats the main problem

Comment: @GauravGarg I understand. That's **exactly** why I suggested using a category. In a separate `.m` file.

Comment: So,I have give it a try and but my property of AFPhotoeditor session of Readonly type

Comment: :After creating Category ,The same problem remains,I am not gettng that what's going on here,and where I will call the two new methods - (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder;
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder;
Currently I am getting the instance of session by the property of EditorCOntroller.Please help me.Thanks in advance,OR these method will automatically called.

Answer (score 0):

Actually creating your own category means that you will have to have it compliant with that object as new ivars are added or changed, forever.

The right way to do this is to determine exactly what you would need to recreate an object of that class - the core values - then create keys and values for each and put them into a dictionary. Put the dictionaries into your user defaults. When you want to retrieve the values, pull out a dictionary, use those values to instantiate the objects.

The other option is to ask the author of AFPhotoeditor to do it, or do it yourself, and send him a pull request. But if you do it as a add on, you will have to update your category everytime the original framework changes.

Comment: But he could just use composition and the public interface of the class. No need for messing with implementation details.

Comment: There is not any method by which I can get the instance of AFPhotoEditorSession from its properties.

Comment: @GauravGarg Then there's no way to persist them to disk. If you can't reconstruct an instance using its properties, then it needs context, and as such, it's not serializable. Sorry.

Comment: @H2CO3 yes, my point was if he used public ivars, and that is all that is needed, but they change in the future, then he has to manage that. If there is internal state info that he cannot actuate via creating the object through some public interface, well, then as you said he is SOOL.